# Retrieving image from the internet with a click of a button and displaying it in another view

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have a button called **loginwith facebook** in the **2nd view**.

If i click on that button, the **facebook api** that i've used should retrieve the image from the internet and should display it in the **5th view**. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options. Save the image in nsuserdefaults or saving it locally would be a good option.

Comment: No. The image should be retrieved from the internet and not by saving it locally. The login with facebook button should directly access the internet, retrieve the image and should display it in the next view.